# What is the speed for the following methods to get the absolute value?

Tags: c++, c++11

Task: check if x (double) is very close to zero using a threshold of let's say 1e-8. Which led me to two performance questions.

Methods I currently use:

1: The save method for when I'm unsure if the data is completely positive or not.

```
double threshold = 0.00000001;
if ( abs(x) < threshold );
 //remove x
```

2: If I'm pretty sure that the data is completely positive.

```
if ( x < threshold )
 //remove x
```

So that leads me to my first question, is the second method faster than the first method or not? I just always assumed the second method to be faster...

Another way I've been thinking about as an alternative to method 1 would be to use

```
if ( x < threshold && x > -threshold )
 //remove x
```

Which leads me to my second question, is this method faster or slower than method 1?

Comment: Why don't you measure it?

Comment: because that would give me an answer without an explanation.

Comment: Unfortunately reasoning about performance tends to just not work. Experts may take a guess first but then just measure. Understanding the compiler/optimizer in enough detail to guess the generated assembly code and then understanding caching, prefetching, reordering of operations and executing multiple instructions in parallel inside the CPU to make an accurate prediction is just way beyond what a human brain is capable of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If in doubt, profile it: compilers are clever at making optimisations these days. If you want to delve deeper, check the generated assembly.

*Conceptually* though, `abs(x)` has the overhead of a function call that must return by value a floating point `double.` Ditto the unary negation `-threshold`. Granted the short-circuting of `&&` reduces the probability of the evaluation of `-threshold`.

So certainly `if ( x < threshold )` will be no *slower* than the other two.

Instinctively I'd plump for `abs` over the negation since, most importantly it's the *clearest* way of expressing what you want to do. Furthermore the compiler may be able to optimise it more readily as it's a standard function. In IEEE754, `abs` is no more than setting the sign bit.

Comment: `abs()` is a fairly common candidate for inlining.

Answer (score 0):

The performance of `abs` depends on the implementation and optimization level. I don't think there's a single correct answer to which one is faster.
Practically I'll always stick to `abs`. As Bathsheba points out, it could be as fast as a single instruction and it offers a clear idea of what your code is doing. Plus I really see little point in such "optimization". It has trivial impact on the perforamce of virtually any program. If you are so serious about performance at this level you should probably write assembly code yourself.